# Proper setup of ASP.NET MVC 3 app with Ninject.MVC3 nuget package

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, nuget

I just added the Ninject.MVC3 nuget package (v2.2.2.0) to my ASP.NET MVC 3 app.

I seem to have set up my ASP.NET MVC 3 app in two different ways:

1. By inheriting from `NinjectHttpApplication` in Global.asax.cs
2. By loading a `NinjectModule` in the `RegisterServices` method in NinjectMVC3.cs

And now I'm trying to make sense of [this blog entry](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/02/22/ninject-mvc3-and-ninject-web-mvc3-merged-to-one-package/), referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064766/whats-the-proper-way-to-configure-ninject-for-an-mvc3-application). It seems to be saying there's yet another method. Something about `NinjectHttpApplicationModule`. I'm lost.

How should I modify my NinjectMVC.cs and Global.asax.cs files? What I have now is pasted below.

---

**NinjectMVC3.cs**

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(TennisClub.App_Start.NinjectMVC3), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivator.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(TennisClub.App_Start.NinjectMVC3), "Stop")]

namespace MyApp.App_Start
{
    using System.Reflection;
    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;
    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Mvc;
    using TennisClub.Configuration;

    public static class NinjectMVC3 
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(HttpApplicationInitializationModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Load(new MainModule()); // I added this
        }        
    }
}
```

**Global.asax**

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication // new
    {
        protected override void OnApplicationStarted() // new
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new CustomModelMetadataProvider();
            ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider(new AttributedValidatorFactory()));
            DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
        }

        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = Token.Home, action = Token.Index, id = UrlParameter.Optional }); // Parameter defaults
        }

        protected override IKernel CreateKernel() // new
        {
            return new StandardKernel(new MainModule());
        }
    }
}
```

**MainModule.cs**

```
namespace MyApp.Configuration
{
    public class MainModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<AppSettings>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
            Bind<MainDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
            Bind<HttpContext>().ToMethod(context => HttpContext.Current);
            Bind<UserInfo>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this page from the Wiki on GitHub -

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application

It goes through both the different approaches and has helped me in the past.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like you are saying I should just revert my Global.asax to its original form and use the `App_Start.NinjectMVC3` class. But what is `NinjectHttpApplicationModule`?

Comment: Looks like the page you referenced is more recent than the blog post (which is where I was getting confused about `NinjectHttpApplicationModule`), so I guess I'm going to try that for now. I have some other things to figure out before I can test whether it works, but +1 for your help.